# Ignoring fields from CSV using pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Problem statement:**
I have a CSV file pipe-delimited with two fields in it.

I am creating a dataframe and adding new columns to it and assigning values through literals.

Now let's say if I have a CSV file received with 5 fields and I still want to consider the first two fields and ignore other new fields and proceed to create a dataframe and to add new columns to it.

Is it possible. Can someone help me on it.

Comment: spark will read complete data into dataframe then you can take only required column from that.

Comment: What is your problem ? What did you try so far ? You can use `drop` to remove fields, or `select` to select only wanted fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve this

**Using pandas**

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', usecols=[0, 1], index_col=0)
spark_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(df)
```

---

**Using RDDs**

```
df = spark_session.textFile('path/to/file.csv') \
    .map(lambda row: row.split(",")) \
    .map(lambda row : (row[0], row[1])) \
    .toDF(['col1', 'col2'])
```